# Find how many times a number appear in a column between date range

Tags: excel-formula

In sheet1 A3:A100 I have Students ID numbers. In sheet1 B3:B100 I have dates
Now i want to put an ID and start date and end date in cells on another sheet and reflect the number of times the ID appear in the date range. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNTIFS to count them:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A3:A100,A2,Sheet1!B3:B100,">="&B2,Sheet1!B3:B100,"<="&C2)
```

Where:

`A2` is the student ID

`B2` is the start date

`C3` is the end date

[example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15wqYSJbYRh8kAcs7Vg1ICSkYGLPSFAQ7zPonXeGzADM/edit?usp=sharing)